# Getting unwanted black bg around text at the time of loading my webpage

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am getting an unwanted black background beneath the text on webpage while loading. Though it disappears when hovered.

I am not able to trace why it is happening, I doubt it is happening because of transition animation css, but I am looking for a solution.

This is the issue:

[here http://183.182.84.84/Picture1.png](http://183.182.84.84/Picture1.png)

Please help me!

Comment: In which browser, in my machine i can't able to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to provide some CSS/HTML code at least. There is little way for people to find your problem without showing them the code.

I did go to the site based of the URL bar and I have no issues with black backgrounds whatsoever. It is most likely your PC that has some custom coloring theme.

[image: Website]